# Bash : redirect init.d output in variable

Tags: bash, nginx, sh

I try to redirect the output of an init.d command to a variable without displaying it on screen, but this does not work.
For example this works :

```
$> var=`uname -a`
$> echo $var
$> Linux
```

But not this :

```
$> var=`/etc/init.d/nginx reload`
$> the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
$> echo $var
$> Reloading nginx configuration: nginx.
```

How can we do to return nothing on the screen please?
Thanks.

Nico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nginx -t` writes those messages on standard error, not on standard output, so you need to capture those too:

```
# var=`nginx -t 2>&1`
# echo $var
the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
#
```

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely possible it is going to stderr instead of stdout.  You could try something like this:

```
var=`/etc/init.d/nginx reload 2>&1`
```

to test.

Comment: I think you forgot to add the backticks

Comment: Weird.  I put them in, but they didn't translate. hmm

Comment: Fixed by indenting four spaces, which turns on the code formatting.